# get user membership in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to get if request user has membership in my site or not but I got an error can any one help me?
user memebership model is

```
    class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_membership')
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, related_name='membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

serializer is :

```
    class UserMemberShipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserMembership
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'membership']
```

and view is

```
    class MembershipView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = UserMembership
    serializer_class = UserMemberShipSerializer

    def get_user_membership(self):
        user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        print(user_membership_qs)
        if user_membership_qs.exists():
            return user_membership_qs.first()

    def get_queryset(self):
        current_membership = self.get_user_membership(self.request)
        return current_membership
```

and error is in this line

```
            current_membership = self.get_user_membership(self.request)
```

the error is
'current_membership = self.get_user_membership(self.request)
TypeError: get_user_membership() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

Answer (score 0):

Remove "self.request" from the input of the get_user_membership function:

```
current_membership = self.get_user_membership()
```

or add "request" as arg to function:

```
    def get_user_membership(self,request):
        user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.get(user=request.user)
        print(user_membership_qs)
        if user_membership_qs.exists():
            return user_membership_qs.first()
```